# installing openBLAS for R on macbook

Tags: r, macos, openblas

I am looking for a faster way of calculating cosine similarity (because I have a large matrix of 2.8Gb).

I found a coop package where was written something about "A good BLAS library," so I started digging and found out that I should use openBLAS library to make it faster. I read [the installation guide](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/wiki/Installation-Guide) and many other articles.

How can I install and run it in R on macbook?

Comment: I don't think there's an R API for that.  Try writing your own cosine similarity function.  See: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31565/is-there-an-r-function-that-will-compute-the-cosine-dissimilarity-matrix

Comment: I don't think there's much improvement possible for this question, but I tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

osX has a great blas library already installed which you can use as an alternative. you only need to link it:

```
# use faster vecLib library
cd /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib
ln -sf  /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/Current/libBLAS.dylib libRblas.dylib
```

[see here for source and details](https://gist.github.com/nicebread/6920c8287d7bffb03007)

Comment: thanks! And is that everything I should do? Just write this 2 rows in terminal?

Comment: this workaround is not working with BigSur and above as they don't ship with the accelerate framework

Comment: @blazej R binaries on CRAN provides vecLib-based BLAS now. Can change to it by creating a symlink.https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/RMacOSX-FAQ.html#Which-BLAS-is-used-and-how-can-it-be-changed_003f

Answer (score 0):

Do not use OpenBLAS on osX. Apple already has a very optimized version of BLAS which is **vecLib**.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is no longer available now.